# How to get the lowest number of one column in a two dimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, c++17

I have a simple program to get from the user the **lowest & highest temperature**, then I must make the program get the average of the lowest & highest temperature of the day.
I should put the 7days,low,high in a two dimensional arrays name temp `temp[7][2]={0};.
so I made the program and it's work well and this is the code;

```
    //declare arr & varaibles 
    int temp[7][2]={0}; // temperature array 
    double totalHigh=0,totalLow=0; //total low temp days & total high temp days
    int high=temp[0][0],low=temp[0][0];// assign the first row & column in array to get the highest & lowest number
    
    for(int row=0;row<7;row+=1){ // for loop to get through every row 
        cout << "Day " << row+1 << endl; 
        cout << "Low: "; cin >> temp[row][0]; // first column is for low temp days
        totalLow += temp[row][0] ; // get the total low days from the user
        cout << "High: "; cin >> temp[row][1]; // second column is for high temp days
        totalHigh += temp[row][1]; // get the total high days from the user
    }

    for(int j=0;j<7;j+=1){ // go through first column to get the high number of it
        if(high < temp[j][0]){
            high = temp[j][0];
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<7;j+=1){ // go though second column to get the low number of it
        if(low > temp[j][1]){
            low = temp[j][1];
        }
    }

    //display on screen 
    cout << fixed<< setprecision(2);
    cout << "Low: "<< totalLow/7 << endl; //get the average of low
    cout << "High: " <<totalHigh/7 << endl;// get the average of high
    cout << "Lowest Of High column: " << low << endl;
    cout << "Highst Of Low column: " << high << endl;
```

but I should also get the highest number of low column & the lowest number of high column.
i get the lowest number of high column, but when I make the loop to get the lowest number it doesn't work.
this is the code of the two loops that go through every column and get them;

```
    for(int j=0;j<7;j+=1){ // go through first column to get the high number of it
        if(high < temp[j][0]){
            high = temp[j][0];
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<7;j+=1){ // go though second column to get the low number of it
        if(low > temp[j][1]){
            low = temp[j][1];
        }
    }
```

but second loop is not working while the first loop is working, can anyone tell me why the second loop is not working?

Comment: Can you share a sample input, the output you're getting, and the expected output?

Comment: Have you looked at the tools in the standard [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) library, like [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have init `low` to `0`.

When you first init the 2d array, all values are set to 0. Then you have init `low` to `temp[0][0]`, which means `low` is `0` now. Unless your lowest high is actually below 0, then it would never be updated.

Similarly, if your highest low is below 0, you would also notice that the `high` is not working properly either.

A way you can fix it is that you only init the `high` and `low` after user already input all the data. And init `high = temp[0][0], low = temp[0][1]`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `c++17` tag I am suggesting this as much better and modern (STLish) solution:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> temp(7);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "Day " << i + 1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Low: ";
        std::cin >> temp.at(i).first;
        std::cout << "High: ";
        std::cin >> temp.at(i).second;
    }
    
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    
    std::cout << "Average Low: " << (std::accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0.0F, [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a + b.first; })) / temp.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average High: " << (std::accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0.0F, [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a + b.second; })) / temp.size() << std::endl;
    
    auto [low_low, high_low]   = std::minmax_element(temp.begin(), temp.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.first < b.first; });
    auto [low_high, high_high] = std::minmax_element(temp.begin(), temp.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.second < b.second; });
    
    std::cout << "Lowest low temperature: " << (*low_low).first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Highest low temperature: " << (*high_low).first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Lowest high temperature: " << (*low_high).second << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Highest high temperature: " << (*high_high).second << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel I would rather use a 2D structure instead of `pair` to get rid of the lambdas, but I don't know if that's still `c++17` approach anymore

Comment: @Ranoiaetep What is "a 2D structure"? If by that you mean a structure having two members, then even you'll have to use lambdas. A way of avoiding lambdas is using two vectors, say `low_temp` and `high_temp`.

Comment: I meant a nested vector, like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 2>`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yeah you can do if you want. I tried to emphasis use of `std::accumulate` and `std::minmax_element`. Why write the code that's already implemented in the standard libraries!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is your low variable initialization.

```
low=temp[0][0];
```

You can modify this loop in this way:

```
auto low = temp[0][1];
for(int j=1;j<7;j+=1) // go though second column to get the low number of it
    if(low > temp[j][1])
        low = temp[j][1];
```

And it should works correctly. I think that start value of low is too low and that's why the lowest value from the highest temperature cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
int high=INT_MIN,low=INT_MAX;
```

This will give you lowest of the high column and highest of the low column.